# splitting the y axis into a linear and logarithmic scale matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I would like to split the y axis into a linear and logarithmic scale section while plotting the figure. For example, from 1-30 a linear scale and from 30 - 100 a logarithmic scale. Is there any way of doing that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a direct method for this. However, you can join both regions (linear and log) manually. See attached code:

```
clc; clear;

x = 1:100; % Values to plot

xorg = 0:10:100; % Ticks on the Y-axis
xticks = xorg; % Final tick location

x1 = log10(30);  % start of logarithmic scale
x2 = log10(100); % end of logarithmic scale

dx = (x2-x1)*60; % 60 here is an arbitrary scaling factor

scale = @(x)(log10(x)-x1)/(x2-x1)*dx+30; % Scaling from lin to log

x(x>30) = scale(x(x>30)); % Apply scaling to plotting values
xticks(xticks>30) = scale(xticks(xticks>30)); % Apply scaling to Y ticks

plot(x);
ylim([0 max(xticks)]);
set(gca,'YTick',xticks,'YTickLabel',xorg); % Update the ticks
```

This produces a plot as below.
[image: Linear and logarithmic scale in one plot]